# Configuring wamp mysql to use innodb not working - error 123

Tags: mysql, wamp, innodb

I get this in the error log (wamp):

```
140205 22:57:41  InnoDB: Operating system error number 123 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File name C:\wampin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data\ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I don't understand what else to do as I have uncommented the commands and changed the paths appropriately:

```
# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
innodb_data_home_dir = C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data/
innodb_log_arch_dir = C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 50M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 10M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 50M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 80M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file, you need to specify the paths as *escaped* Windows-style paths using double backslashes (`\\`), for example:

```
innodb_data_home_dir = C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.8\\data\\
```

In your case the `\b` is getting replaced because it's a valid control code, causing your path to become invalid. I believe you could also use forward slashes(`/`) instead of double backslashes (`\\`).

Answer (score 0):

In your my.ini you should change all the DOS directory seperators to UNIX ones, so

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\data/
```

Should be

```
C:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.8/data/
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look to the my.init file in your wamp server. In this file, there is a commented part allowing you to use INNODB engine. It works for me.